# Insert,upadate in single Procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

im creating stored procedure in my sql but getting error,error shows as below,help me Error Descrption:You hve an error in your sql syntax: ckeck the manual that corresponds to your MYSQL

server version fro the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 13

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS myhealthcamp.area $$
CREATE PROCEDURE myhealthcamp.area
(
  IN id INT,
  IN ar VARCHAR(45)
)
BEGIN
if exists (select area_id from area where area_id = id)
Then
  update area set areaname = ar where area_id=id;
else
  insert into area(area_id, areaname) values(id,ar);
END IF
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `;` in this line:

```
END IF
```

It should be:

```
END IF;
```

`IF` is a statement and all statements must end in semi-colons. This one's no different. See the [MySQL documentation for `IF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if-statement.html).

Comment: thanks,one more doudbt i hve,how write return value as message like "Insert successfully" or "Update successfully" in procedure.

Comment: @xcodemaddy Ooh, I wouldn't know. My sql knowledge is not *that* wide. Perhaps ask that as another question? I'd be interested in seeing the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS myhealthcamp.area $$
CREATE PROCEDURE myhealthcamp.area
(
  IN id INT,
  IN ar VARCHAR(45)
)
BEGIN
if exists (select area_id from area where area_id = id)
Then
  update area set areaname = ar where area_id=id;
else
  insert into area(area_id, areaname) values(id,ar);
END IF;
```

semicolon missing

Thanks
Sanil